# How can I keep label not closed in MUI 5 datepicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datepicker

Is there a way to keep Material 5 Datepicker to not close if there's a label but no value?

Currently:
[Currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKVa3.png)

What I try to get:
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akPaB.png)

Code:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
  <DatePicker
    label="Basic example"
    value={value}
    onChange={(newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

I tried to make an own `<Box>` label above `<DatePicker>` with styling but I was wondering if there is a cleaner option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}` prop on your `TextField` component like this:

```
<DatePicker
  label="Basic example"
  value={value}
  onChange={(newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} />}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I tried this before but without the space bars what was actually something important

Answer (score 1):

```js
<DatePicker
  label="Basic example"
  slotProps={{ textField: { InputLabelProps: { shrink: true } } }}
/>
```

Maybe, helps someone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).